# want to use python 3 code in python 2.x (getting error)

Tags: python

i want to use python 3 code file in python 2.x evan i converted whole file in 2.x via 3to2.py but one thing i am still getting error here you can see

> course_title = course_title.text.strip().replace(u" ", u"_")
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

kindly help me to solve my issue
i am not expert in python but i am keep trying

here is my code file

```
# Get all episodes
course = session_requests.get(course_page)
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(course.content, u"lxml")
course_title = soup2.find(u"h1", {
    u"class": u"series-title"
})
course_title = course_title.text.strip().replace(u" ", u"_")
print u"Course title: " + course_title
```

its working now but getting new two new errors after this

> filename = download_file(url, session_requests, course_title)   File
>   "sts.py", line 25, in download_file
>       parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url) AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'urlparse'

Comment: No `h1` element was found and `course_title` became `None`.

Comment: You forgot to check if `course_title` can actually be found in that HTML file, and you are assuming it will always be there.

Comment: After your edit: consider changing to Python 3 and see if all of your problems magically go away.

Comment: everything is working in python 3 but getting this error in python 2.x

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find), `find` will return `None` when it can't find the result you're looking for. You need to explicitly guard against this in your code, regardless of the python version:

```
if course_title:
    course_title = course_title.text.strip().replace(u" ", u"_")
    print u"Course title: " + course_title
```

Comment: dear now with other url getting this error                                           filename = download_file(url, session_requests, course_title)

Comment: parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'urlparse'